# How to use the PHP unlink function?

Tags: php

I try to delete files with PHP. First I try to make a function to delete files but I want to delete one specific file and not all in the folder.

My function:

```
<?php
    function del_tmp($file_name) 
    { 
        $dir = "mod_download/"; 
        $verz = opendir($dir); 
        while ($file_name = readdir ($verz))  
        { 
            if($file_name != "." && $file_name != "..")  
            { 
                unlink($dir.$file_name); 
            } 
        } 
        closedir($verz);  
    }  
    ?>
```

I think the problem is in this line: `if($file_name != "." && $file_name != "..")` but I have no idea how can i fix it.

Comment: use glob option.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: You have 2 variable with the name `$file_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than processing over a whole directory as you only want to delete one file would it not be simpler and quicker to do

```
<?php
    function del_tmp($file_name) 
    { 
        $dir = "mod_download/"; 
        if ( file_exists($dir . $filename) ) {
            unlink($dir . $file_name); 
        } 
    }  
?>
```